# Nested SELECT returning more than one record

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to return the transfer amount where the record is marked as active = 1 and the date is the greatest.

```
SELECT 
    MAX(transfer_date)
FROM
    brew_transfer
WHERE
    brew_id = 20 AND active = 1
```

works perfectly and returns '2018-03-20 12:00:00' as it should.

However when I nest it inside another select I am getting two records returned; 1800 which I expect and 1500 which record has the max date but for an inactive record...

```
SELECT 
    brew_transfer.transfer_amount
FROM
    brew_transfer
WHERE
    transfer_date = (SELECT 
        MAX(transfer_date)
    FROM
        brew_transfer
    WHERE
        (brew_id = 20 AND active = 1))
```

Data is as below

```
brew_transfer_id active brew_id status_id transfer_date transfer_amount 
        16         0       20       4       2018-03-22        1500              
        19         1       20       2       2018-03-18        1850              
        20         1       20       3       2018-03-20        1800
```

Can anyone help me with what I am doing wrong? Is there a way to do this without creating a temp table and some update code?

Thanks

Comment: Your query looks correct, this is your actual query? Is it possible to have another predicate that you are not sharing?

Comment: It's working correctly for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef2ec0/2

Comment: Maybe your sample data here isn't the same as your actual data? Try using `select *` instead of `select transfer_amount` to see which rows you're actually getting.

Comment: If you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your first query which is

```
SELECT 
    MAX(transfer_date)
FROM
    brew_transfer
WHERE
    brew_id = 20 AND active = 1
```

You are getting `2018-03-20 12:00:00` as you mentioned. 
Now you are inserting in the second query which make it:

```
SELECT 
    brew_transfer.transfer_amount
FROM
    brew_transfer
WHERE
    transfer_date = 2018-03-20 12:00:00)
```

According to this query you are getting right result as you don't mentioned that you want record `where active = 1` in second query

Answer:

```
SELECT 
    brew_transfer.transfer_amount
FROM
    brew_transfer
WHERE
    (brew_id = 20 AND active = 1) 
ORDER BY 
    transfer_date 
DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Your query fails when there is more than one record having `MAX(transfer_date)`.

Comment: for a particular id and active =1 . there is no possibility to have more than one records.

Comment: If brew_id is different then there is possibility for more than one record having max(transfer_date) .

Comment: In this query if you are getting more than one results than the other results having lower transfer_amount. But according to question he want max result so I use Limit 1. remove Limit 1 you will all results

Answer (score 0):

Your second version of query is working as you expect.

```
select * from brew_transfer t
where transfer_date  = (select max(transfer_date) 
                        from brew_transfer where brew_id = 20 AND active = 1)
```

However, you could also do that via correlate  approach

```
select * from brew_transfer t
where brew_id = 20 and transfer_date = (
      select max(transfer_date) from brew_transfer 
      where brew_id = t.brew_id and active = 1)
```

However, you don't need to filter `brew_id` in `subquery` casue `outer query` has already applied filter on `brew_id`.

Comment: Your second version will only return rows where `brew_id = 20`. He wants to use that when getting the max date, but it doesn't look like he wants to use that when selecting all the rows for that date.

Answer (score -1):

Try always including relevant table names or aliases against ALL column references.

```
SELECT
      brew_transfer.transfer_amount
FROM brew_transfer
WHERE brew_transfer.transfer_date = (
      SELECT
            MAX(bt.transfer_date)
      FROM brew_transfer bt
      WHERE (bt.brew_id = 20
      AND bt.active = 1)
      )
```

Comment: You don't need to use aliases to distinguish tables in a subquery.